# How to add modification to the Kannel and then update

Tags: kannel

I want to customize Kannel according to my requirements.

If I have changed the source files or add some source files, how do I commit those changes (compile and update), without configure and install from the beginning?

If I add some source files (*.c and *.h), is there a naming rules for those files?

(There should be a compatible way to develop and test it. That's what I want to know)

Can anybody help me on this?

Thank You!

Suranga.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend first read README file from Kannel.
It contains section for developers describing some coding issues and sources tree.

https://redmine.kannel.org/projects/kannel/repository/entry/trunk/README

However it seems better way is to read sources and to follow existing practices unless you add architecture changes.

Comment: `If you modify any source files to add or change any header
includes, you need to run "make depend".
You always need to run "make"`.
I only see this. If this is the way you think, tell me.

Comment: Best way is still to read sources starting from *configure.in* and *Makefile.in*.

You can also read automatically generated [doxygen pages](http://doxygen.kannel.org/main.html) to observe code.